# Locations while in background

Tags: ios8, core-location

Sorry if this one's a bit of a stupid question.

I'm currently building an iOS app which needs to be able to have (or acquire) the user's location when a push notification is received, potentially waking up the app. Previously, I was just monitoring significant location changes, updating a property as locations were received, using the last acquired location when the push notification is received (the location doesn't need to be very accurate, within 0.5-1.0 km will suffice).

However, with the highly annoying changes to location permissions in iOS8, this now requires 'always' authorisation - which repeatedly prompts the user about the access, greatly increasing the chances it will be turned off altogether. So my question is basically twofold. Will 'when in use' authorisation allow the location to be accessed even when the app is in the background, woken up by a push notification? And if it will, is there anything special I need to do to get the location - for example, wait a few seconds for the GPS to acquire a position, or make a call to enable location monitoring?